# Executing a SQL file by running a batch file

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to put together a batch file to simply execute a .sql file I have.  The code I'm using in the batch is:

```
REM JOB.BAT

SQLPLUS -S username/password@db @C:\Users\username\Desktop\testsql.sql


EXIT
```

I am getting the error:

"ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified"

I think the issue is that my password contains the @ symbol, so it starts reading the remote database name in the middle of the password instead of just reading 'db'.  So if my password were "p@ssword", it's looking for a database called "ssword@db" which does not exist.

Is there a short way around this or is changing my password the only way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you TNS isn't setup correctly you can simply call the database explicitly:

Comment: you could try putting quotes round username/password@db, but to be honest i think your best bet is to change the password

Comment: [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/connect.htm#i435636) could hardly be more vague. It suggests you can quote the second part (what's aftet the @ sign) but says nothing about passwords...

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the password string, using whatever is appropriate for your operating system.  It looks like you're using Windows, so, try this:

```
SQLPLUS -S username/'password'@db @C:\Users\username\Desktop\testsql.sql
```

Comment: [This article](http://www.thebonsai.net/2011/03/24/escaping-special-characters-in-sqlplus-logon-strings/) seems to confirm this. I've browsed Oracle documentation many times and I've never been able to find official reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you TNS isn't setup correctly you can simply call the database explicitly:

```
sqlplus 'user/pass@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=hostname.network)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=remote_SID)))'
```